# Pre-populate BuddyPress Member Profile Data in Gravity Forms

Tags: buddypress, plugin-gravity-forms

I am succesfully pre populating logged in user wordpress user meta into gravity forms, but I can't find a way how to prepopulate buddypress profile data into gravity forms.

**Goal**

I want to be able to pull from Buddypress Profile data for the logged in user to populate the fields in Gravity forms such as Phone, Address, Country, Province etc.

**Conclusion**

I hope that buddypress member profile fields works very similarly as wordpress user_meta does, I tried many combinations which I have found on the net and nothing works for me - (for example the name of one of the fields in buddypress profile fields is Phone - group_id=5&field_id=59 - this is the slug from edit profile page, which should say that Phone's fields number is 59 and group 5(I don't know if it is important):

This is the code which should be pulling Buddypress xprofile fields which unfortunately doesn't work.

```
add_filter("form_field_value_phone", "populate_phone");
function populate_phone() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $phone = bp_profile_field_data( array('user_id'=>$current_user_id,'field'=>'Phone' ));
    return $phone;
}
```

This is working "wordpress" user meta data fields in functions.php

```
// populate the field with "user_firstname" as the population parameter with the "first_name" of the current user
    add_filter('gform_field_value_user_firstname', create_function("", '$value = populate_usermeta(\'first_name\'); return $value;' ));

// populate the field with "user_lastname" as the population parameter with the "last_name" of the current user
        add_filter('gform_field_value_user_lastname', create_function("", '$value = populate_usermeta(\'last_name\'); return $value;' ));

// this function is called by both filters and returns the requested user meta of the current user
        function populate_usermeta($meta_key){
            global $current_user;
            return $current_user->__get($meta_key);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For somebody who will need it too, I got that working with this snippet (it works with text fields, dropdown should be different):

```
    add_filter("gform_field_value_city", "populate_city");
function populate_city($value){
     global $current_user;
     get_currentuserinfo();
     return xprofile_get_field_data('city', $current_user->ID);
}
```

and Gravity Forms

```
Parameter Name = city
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `xprofile_get_field($field_id)` or `xprofile_get_field_data($field, $user_id)`? They are there in the BuddyPress code to give you fields data.

Comment: Thanks for your respond @slaffik, I am using gravity forms for 4 custom post types as portfolio,job board-searching-offering jobs, all of them use GF to create applicant,portfolio, employeretc. pages which should be fill out more than once,that's why I was thinking to make it more easy for people to fill out once first buddypress fields with basic data and then easily fill out every job request-offer form by auto populating half of the form with the basic data from members profile fields, I need to get those data into gravity form's fields, not in buddypress.

Comment: I would like to use buddypress members fields to store all data of people which will then, when logged in use those data to dynamically populate them across the site when creating 4 different custom post types , for example lapdancers searches for job in the club, club advertise their club job offer,to make it easier the girl creates CPT portfolio first with all personal data which sends to buddypress fields DB, then when she wants to search for a job, she can create job request to work somewhere, then she can fill out job-search form and there her data can be dynamically populated